# Generic types with VSCode intellisense not the same when using imported method

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics, react-tsx

So when using React with TS, I'm trying to make sure everything is correctly autocompleted but for some reason when using the imported method the types are different to what the `import` line has, see screenshots below in VSCode:

In `import` line:

[image: In import line]

Mentioning the method within the same file, shows the following:

[image]

This means that the const `post` is always `any` which sucks for autocompletion and TS goodness.

Have tried uninstalling some VSCode plugins and even tried it in my MacOS environment and linux but getting the same result probably due to using the same VSCode config in both OS's

Comment: Going to type definition on the `any` version of the method is actually showing up the correct type with generics, not sure where VSCode is getting this random type

Comment: Oh and React version is `18.2.0`